# how to create an intranet mailing system using java

Tags: java

i want to create an intranet mailing system using java.so suggest me which API and what classes to use.

Comment: do you have a mail server set up - and just want to connect via java?

Comment: i just want to connect via java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html)

Comment: This only gives you the MUA side of the equation.  You also need an MTA implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Without doubts use [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) - it's an industry standard.

Commons Email aims to provide a API for sending email. It is built on top of the Java Mail API, which it aims to simplify.

Some of the mail classes that are provided are as follows:

- **SimpleEmail** - This class is used to send basic text based emails.
- **MultiPartEmail** - This class is used to send multipart messages. This allows a text message with attachments either inline or attached.
- **HtmlEmail** - This class is used to send HTML formatted emails. It has all of the capabilities as MultiPartEmail allowing attachments to be easily added. It also supports embedded images.
- **EmailAttachment** - This is a simple container class to allow for easy handling of attachments. It is for use with instances of MultiPartEmail and HtmlEmail.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: http://github.com/masukomi/aspirin
It can actually send email (some kind of embedded MTA):

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
       MailQue que = new MailQue();
       MimeMessage mes = SimpleMimeMessageGenerator.getNewMimeMessage();
       mes.setText("test body");
       mes.setSubject("test subject");
       mes.setFrom(new InternetAddress("my@local.com"));
       mes.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "foo@bar.com");
       que.queMail(mes);
   }
}
```